# Failed to get the result I wanted in Oracle from Sql server

Tags: sql-server, oracle

This code in Sql Server.But I'm trying to conver it in Oracle but failed.It may be a simple task but I could not done it as I'm still learning.Please help.

```
DECLARE @StartDateTime DATETIME='2017-01-01 00:00:00'
DECLARE @EndDateTime DATETIME='2017-12-31 23:59:59';
```

This is what I've done so far in Oracle .But showing error .

```
  DECLARE StartDateTime  DATE='2017-01-01 00:00:00'
  EndDateTime  DATE='2017-12-31 23:59:59';
```

Comment: "But showing error"....perhaps you could share that error?

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax for [timestamp literal](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#BABGIGCJ) is:

```
declare 
    StartDateTime date := timestamp '2017-01-01 00:00:00';
    EndDateTime   date := timestamp '2017-12-31 23:59:59';
begin
    -- do something here
    dbms_output.put_line(StartDateTime);
    dbms_output.put_line(EndDateTime);
end;
```